# How do I open a modal in the current page after I call the php file?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

My problem is, 
I have an HTML file that has a contact form which is shown in below:

```
<form method="post" action="send-email.php" name="contactform">
    <div class="row uniform">
        <div class="6u 12u$(xsmall)">
            <input type="text" name="user-name" id="demo-name" value="" placeholder="Name" />
        </div>
        <div class="6u$ 12u$(xsmall)">
            <input type="email" name="user-email" id="demo-email" value="" placeholder="Email" />
        </div>
        <div class="12u$">
            <textarea name="user-message" id="demo-message" placeholder="Enter your message" rows="6"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="12u$">
            <ul class="actions">
                <li>
                    <input type="submit" value="Send Message" class="special" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

As seen in the code, form method is post and it goes to "send-email.php" after it is sent. When everything is done and the client sends the form, I want to show a modal on the same page and also run "send-email.php". PHP file ends with the following code when everything is done correctly:

```
header('Location: contact-form-thank-you.html');
```

I don't want to redirect to another html page, I want to show a modal on the same page. How do I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

user ajax for send request

In html change

```
<form id="nyform" name="contactform">   
    ...

    <li><input id="submitform" type="button" value="Send Message" class="special" /></li>
```

Add Modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="mymodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="smallModal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Title here</h4>
       </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Content here</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Close</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="okay">OK</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Add javascript

```
<script>
        function getInput()
        {
             var inputs = {};
             inputs['user-name'] = $("#demo-name").val();
             ...
             return inputs;
        }

        jQuery(document).ready( function() {
            $('#submitform').click(function(){
                //get input
                var inputs = getInput();
                $.ajax({
                   type:'GET',
                   url: "send-email.php",
                   data: inputs,
                   async: false,
                   success:function(result){
                       $('#mymodal').modal('show');
                   }
                });
            })

        });

    </script>
```

Comment: I guess you didn't understand what my problem is. Or your answer didn't solve it. I applied your answer on my site, I get the same thing. When I click the button, it goes to "send-email.php" and as there is nothing in there, I see a blank page. What I want is I want to click the button and I want php to work and also show a modal on the same page where I clicked the button.

Comment: OK, can you print all the input you got in send-email.php after you applied my code in your site

Comment: OK, I managed to do the right thing however I get an error. The error is: **HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed**, _The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) is being used._ After I clicked [view more information](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/942051/error-message-when-a-user-visits-a-website-that-is-hosted-on-a-server-that-is-running-internet-information-services-7.0-http-error-405.0---method-not-allowed) I figured out that my problem is "Cause 2". Could you help me now?

Comment: OK I see, you change the method from POST to GET. I will edit in post and when you want to get the value in send-email.php page you use $_GET['user-name'], I hope this help

Comment: OK, I'll try this and get back to you. A little question, why did you define an id called "nyform" to the form tag?

Comment: actually I want to use myform but I type wrong. In this case I don't use that id.

Comment: I give up bro, this ain't gonna work. Page is reloading, mail is not coming and modal is not showing. I'll share the whole code including PHP, but I don't know where I'm making a wrong move. Thank you very much.